# Sending SMS to a Specific Port

Tags: java, sms, gsm

I know how to send SMS messages through a GSM modem, but I am trying to send a message to a specific port, e.g. 5000. I don't have any idea how to do this; please help me.

Comment: What language/platform are you using? what have you tried already?

Comment: Java platform,I sending sms throw GSM modem using COM port successfully.But i need to send sms to a Specific Port(ex:5000).

Comment: mobile have ports, when we sent to 0 port it reaches inbox likewise, how can we sent through port

Comment: i need to send sms using AT+commands to specific port(5000) , can you share more details of this

Answer (score 0):

Time to break out good old GSM 03.40! You need a TP-User-Data field, Information Element Identifier `0x04` and/or `0x05`, depending on which port you want to use. How to do that in your particular API which you have not told us anything about is up to you.

Comment: i need to send sms using AT+commands to specific port(5000) , can you share more details of this.

Comment: More details can be found in GSM 03.40. That’s why I mentioned it. Use Google to find it, it contains everything you need.